# DB2: converting date values to varchar

Tags: sql, database, db2

I am new to databases, in fact this is first time.

I want to select the date column from a table and the date to be printed as an output in some given format, like is there a way i can specify the format of output of this conversion.

eg:

```
date: 01/01/2011
```

output :

```
Jan 1 2011
```

or

```
1st January 2011
```

Is there a function or way to do so? My guess is there must be?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
VARCHAR_FORMAT(DATE, 'MON DD YYYY')
```

[VARCHAR_FORMAT](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007110.html)